# ¿ Long a Float en Java?

Tags: java, datetime

Buenos dias,tengo el siguiente problema obtengo en una variable de tipo Long una conversion de Milisegundos a Horas,Pero requiero almacenarlas en una variable de Tipo Float.

```
 tiempos.setFechaHoraFinal(fechaActual);
    tiemposFacade.edit(tiempos);
    Long diferencia = tiempos.getFechaHoraInicio().getTime() - tiempos.getFechaHoraFinal().getTime();
    long resultado = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diferencia);





    tiempos.setTotalHoraHombre(diferencia.floatValue());
```

Necesito Setear la variable 'resultado' en

```
 tiempos.setTotalHoraHombre(diferencia.floatValue());
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: Es de casualidad para guardarlo en Apache POI? si ese fuera el caso tiene un método en DateUtil.getExcelDate()

Comment: El problema es que no puedo guardar  la variable resultado en un Float, por que es de tipo Long entonces debo transformarla antes, para poder setearla en tiempos.setTotalHoraHombre(); para que quede asi tiempos.setTotalHoraHombre(resultado);

Comment: ¿Qué clase de diseño tienes que necesitas guardarlo como `float`? Ojo que  al hacerlo se pierde precisión.

Comment: La verdad @LuiggiMendozaJ es que yo capturo dos fechas en Datetime en diferentes momentos del dia o incluso en dias diferentes lo que yo quiero que me guarde en ese campo Float es por ejemplo 2.5 horas 3.0 y asi.

Comment: Ah, pero entonces no tienes que convertir el Long de la fecha a Float, sino la diferencia entre esas dos fechas, en horas.

Answer (score 2):

Como dice @LuiggiMendozaJ te conviene más guardar ese tipo de datos en un objeto más preciso (BigDecimal) haciendo la conversión de la diferencia de horas,  así que a tu pregunta como lo conviertes es diviendolo entre este número (3600000f) la f es para explicar que es float al compilador.

```
float miFloat = diferenciaEnMilisegundos/ 3600000f;
```

De donde sale el número es la multiplicación de 1000 milisegundos que tiene un segundo, 60 segundos tiene un minuto y 60 minutos tiene una hora.

De forma más precisa sería lo siguiente.

```
BigDecimal horasHombre = new BigDecimal(diferenciaEnMilisegundos).divide(new BigDecimal(3600000), 1, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```

Existiendo diferentes tipos de redondeo según te convengan.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html

Si no conoces bien el funcionamiento de la clase BigDecimal, te conviene darle una revisada, puesto que en cualquier operación matemática (Sumas, restas, divisiones, multiplicaciones, etc... ) float o double te darán resultados inesperados por su imprecisión aritmética.